# Cache .js and .css files using Google chrome api

Tags: javascript, css, caching, google-chrome-extension

I use a website which has a very high response time. Most of the time is taken to load a page with its javascript and css files.

I want to write a Google Chrome extension which can save/cache all the js files for a really long time.

I know JS on its own would not provide me this feature. Does google chrome have an api to do the same?

Are there any other options ?

Comment: there are no API's to explicitly cache a specific js or css file on a website(which again has to go through script injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a good idea

- Do you expect people to install this extension, for the sole purpose of visiting your site? I visit hundreds of sites regularly, should I install hundreds of extensions?
- Will you also make an extension for Firefox / Opéra / Safari / whatever browser I like?

If the webserver correctly places the HTTP headers, the browser (Chrome and all others) will cache all resources correctly.

See [How can I improve loading times on a static HTML site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673655/how-can-i-improve-loading-times-on-a-static-html-site)

*Edit*: Now that I better understand your need, what you can do is create an extension that

- is applied on the site in question
- removes the script/css loading, for instance `$('head>stylesheet').remove()`
- injects the same script/css with a local copy, and optionally improves the loading of script with `$(document).ready(main_function)` (rather than `<body.onload="main_function()">`)

Comment: Did I mention its not my site? Its just a site that I visit which is too slow. I want to improvise the performance only for me.\

Comment: I did not understand that. Edited my answer. Note that you'll need to update the extension each time the site is modified

Comment: This sounds like a very good idea. So basically I need to make sure of all the scripts are hosted locally? Can I create a dynamic file if I have the content and then update the scripts tag with those file paths?

Comment: I can save the file contents in local Storage and then append the body of the page with the scripts? Other wise what other option do I have?

Comment: Yes, I suppose, you can externalize this part of the plugin with a local storage. All this will mostly improve the network time, if the javascript does heavy computation, the site will remain slow.